# Formatting a number from a cell into a datatype one in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the column:

[image: period_column]

and I want to format it so I can obtain the year and the month separated by a dot like this:
[image: final_result].

The steps were the following:

1. I converted the value into a text format: =TEXT($A2; "000000")
2. I used left and right functions to separate the year, respectively the month
3. I concatenated them all and I put a dot between them

My question is (because I spent some time): isn't it a simpler method to do all this stuff?

Comment: do you use a single formula such as =CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4),".",RIGHT(A1,2)) or actually do each item separately?

Comment: I did them separately because Excel doesn't let me combine any functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\.00")
```

However, this would output text isntead of true dates. Not something you'd really want in a database. I'd also suggest to use:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),RIGHT(A2,2),1)
```

And use custom number formatting 'yyyy.mm` on your column.

Answer (score 0):

Not simpler but it is useful for Excel to know that your date is really a date.
A date can be used as a date in formulas, sorting, grouping, filters, etc.

Convert the number into a date using the **DATE** function.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),RIGHT(A2,2),1)
```

Set a Custom format by right clicking on a date cell, select *Format Cell* and set a custom format type of:

```
yyyy.mm
```

Copy the Custom format to other cells using the **Format Painter**.

Excel will recognise the cell as a date.
You will see the format that you want.

[image]